# Using a resource_name in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working on a heavy app, and I need the same kind of information in many views.
Is there something existing to replace my model name? I would like to use a generic partial.

For example :

```
Created <%=h date_format(@project.created_at) %> par <%=h @project.user_create.aka rescue nil %>
```

You could have the same thing for project, companies, etc..

I saw "resource_name" in devise which do that. Do you have any tips?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write some helper that generates the output you need